# How do I make a derived class cloneable?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, icloneable

I am attempting to create a base class and a derived class that both implement `ICloneable`. It seems to me that the base class `Clone` method should take care of all the base class properties and the derived class `Clone` method all of the derived class properties and use the base class's `Clone` method. The result is something like this:-

```
Public Class MyBaseClass
    Implements ICloneable

    Private my_base_var As Integer

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements System.ICloneable.Clone
        Dim new_base_class As MyBaseClass = New MyBaseClass
        new_base_class.my_base_var = my_base_var
        Return new_base_class
    End Function

End Class

Public Class MySubClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass
    Implements ICloneable

    Private my_sub_var As Integer

    Public Overloads Function Clone() As Object Implements System.ICloneable.Clone
        Dim new_sub_class As MySubClass = CType(MyBase.Clone, MySubClass)    ' (1)
        new_sub_class.my_sub_var = Me.my_sub_var
        Return new_sub_class
    End Function

End Class
```

This results in a run-time exception `Unable to cast object of type MyBaseClass to type MySubClass` at line (1), which I confess did not surprise me. Replacing that line with

```
    Dim new_sub_class As MySubClass = MyBase.Clone
```

produced a compilation error. It seems to me that I need some way of converting a `MyBaseClass` to `MySubClass` in order to get the base class's members set up with the base class's `Clone`. A less appealing alternative would be to copy the base class's members in the sub-class's `Clone`. Does anyone know what to do here?

I have looked at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103693/cloneable-in-derived-classes) but can't translate that into VB.Net. If the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072206/vb-net-forced-inheritance-through-multiple-generations) is necessary, then I'll give up the idea. In the fullness of time I plan to make the base class `MustInherit`, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Since you do not want to use one of the (unclean) workarounds, maybe a library might help you. AutoMapper may be suitable for your needs (or any other mapping library might do the job as well): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible implementation could look like this:

```
Public Class MyBaseClass
    Implements ICloneable
    Private my_base_var As Integer = 1

    Public Overridable Function Clone() As Object implements ICloneable.Clone
        Dim theClone = Create()
        theClone.my_base_var = my_base_var
        Return theClone
    End Function

    Protected Overridable Function Create() As MyBaseClass
        Return New MyBaseClass()
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MySubClass
    Inherits MyBaseClass
    Private my_sub_var As Integer = 1

    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim theClone = DirectCast(MyBase.Clone(), MySubClass)
        theClone.my_sub_var = Me.my_sub_var
        Return theClone
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function Create() As MyBaseClass
        Return New MySubClass()
    End Function
End Class
```